# A basic shopping cart implementation with Spring-boot and thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, shopping-cart

I am trying to do a very basic shopping cart implementation with spring-boot and thymeleaf. I displayed products on the page in a table. The user chooses products with the checkbox corresponding to that product and provides the quantity of each as number input. After submit button is pressed, I need to create an OrderForm object that has a field called entries, which is a List of OrderFormEntry objects. There is an OrderFormEntry object storing the barcode and quantity of each chosen product.

The relevant parts of my code are the following.

products.html

```
<form class="ui form" th:action="@{/products}" method="post" th:object="${orderForm}">
    <ul>
        <tr th:each="product, ind : ${productDTO.products}">
           
            <input hidden name="barcode" th:value="${product.getBarcode()}"/>

            <td th:text="${product.barcode}"/>
            <td th:text="${product.name}"/>
            <td th:text="${product.description}"/>

            <td>
                <input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="quantity">
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bool" th:value="${product.barcode}" th:field="${orderForm.entries}"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ul>
    <th>
        <div class="field">
            <button class="ui button" type="submit" >Checkout</button>
        </div>
    </th>
</form>
```

OrderFormConverter.java

```
public class OrderFormConverter implements Converter<String, OrderFormEntry> {
@Override
public OrderFormEntry convert(String id) {
    Long parseID = Long.parseLong(id);
    List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
            new Product("ice tea",1L, "tea"),
            new Product("caramel latte",2L, "coffee"),
            new Product("vanilla latte",3L, "coffee")
    );
    List<OrderFormEntry> entries = Arrays.asList(
            new OrderFormEntry(products.get(0).getBarcode(),0), //second parameter should be the quantity of the product
            new OrderFormEntry(products.get(1).getBarcode(),0),
            new OrderFormEntry(products.get(2).getBarcode(),0)
    );

    int index = (int) (parseID -1);

    return entries.get(index);
}
```

}

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public String products(Model model) {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    PS.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(products::add);
    model.addAttribute("productDTO", new ProductDTO(products));
    OrderForm orderForm = new OrderForm();
    model.addAttribute("orderForm", orderForm);
    return "products";
}

@PostMapping("/products")
public String add(@ModelAttribute OrderForm orderForm, @RequestParam(value="quantity") int quantity,
                  @RequestParam(value="barcode") Long barcode) {

//I am not sure about this part


    return "success";
}
```

I can create the objects with the converter just fine, but with this method I could not set the quantity field of OrderFormEntry objects. I am also not very sure about the converter part since i need to provide the products manually, is there a better way to do this?